# Committing partial Hunks in Git

Tags: git, msysgit

If I made two logical changes, which is continuous in code. Git shows it as one single hunk while adding interactively.

Is there a way to specifically add only few lines in a hunk, during `add --patch`?

Comment: This question possibly duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333828/splitting-up-a-git-commit-into-phases-how-to-manually-intervene . The answer to that question adds additional useful detail, too (the `git stash --keep-index` trick).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [`git add --patch` mode](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-add.html) has option for splitting an individual hunk or editing an individual hunk.

[`git add --patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html):

```
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
```

Wouldn't that solve your issue regarding your continuous set of lines?

After adding partials to commit, User should use ONLY `git commit` to commit, using `git commit -a` or using commit with `all files` flag ignores added partial and commits all staged files.

Comment: Note: For me, it was not enough to commit via `git commit` (no `git commit -a`) after adding only some hunks to the index. Even though `git diff` and `git diff --cached` were giving the expected output, as well as `git status`, issuing `git commit` added all the changes altogether to the commit. I had to use `git stash --keep-index` before, to stash the other changes temporarily, to commit partially, and then `git stash pop` to add them back to the working copy. Msysgit 1.7.11 @ WinXP. YMMV.